# Working with Debian 8 and Windows 10 and the EFI partition

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, uefi

I'm trying to install Windows 10 and Debian 8 dual boot.

- Single SATA disk
- System is UEFI so will be GPT
- Using DVD installers for both OS
- Am installing Windows first
- There's no final setup so I can wipe the full disk if required

---

I first tried creating the Linux and Windows partitions in Debian Live:

- EFI (FAT32)
- / (EXT4)
- /home (EXT4)
- swap
- Win (NTFS)

However, running the Windows installer it just returned:

> We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one

Using diskpart (MSDOS via Windows installer "Repair") I formatted to NTFS thinking it might be because I created it with Linux, but installer returned the same message.

After more reading I discovered Windows *now* has a few partitions of its own (eg MSR; EFI; NTFS).

**Question 1:**
Is the requirement of multiple Windows partitions the reason the installer wouldn't accept the (single) NTFS partition I created for it? (I used to be able to just do this pre UEFI/Win 10)

**Question 2:**
Had I deleted the NTFS partition (only), would the Windows installer have successfully used the unallocated space?

---

I then wiped the full disk and just let Windows install automatically. That gave me the 3 Windows partitions MSR; EFI; Data/OS;

**Question 3:**
Will Linux have a problem with the EFI partition being *in between* the Windows MSR and data partitions? Or will Linux installer find the EFI partition and ask if I want to put the Linux EFI there too?
(I ask as seemingly there can only be one EFI partition per disk.)

**Question 4:**
If Linux won't find the Windows created EFI partition and needs to be at the start of the disk (or other requirements), can I manually create the 3 Windows with EFI as the first, then MSR, then data (then later the Linux partitions via Linux installer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Windows requires msr, efi, ntfs partitions. The efi fat32 partition you have created from linux live distro maynot be having efi partition id. Also, as you haven't created msr partition, it could be the reason. Few search results showed me that MSR partition is not mandatory.
2. Yes, Windows chooses the unallocated space and creates required partitions itself.
3. AFAIK, Linux wouldn't have any issue with efi partition position.
4. If linux cannot find efi partition, it will be ok to create partitions in the order efi, msr, ntfs, ext4. I think msr partition should be after efi partition.

Install Windows first and choose manual partitioning. Boot up Windows installation disk and when the  `install windows` button appears, press `Shift + F10` . A command prompt window opens. Enter the command `diskpart` to use command line manual partitioning with diskpart. In diskpart, use the commands. you may need to use this diskpart's command line method of partitioning since the gui way of partitioning during installation may not be able to create efi or msr partition types manually.

- `list disk` -- lists available disks. Say your internal hard disk is listed as number `0`.
- `select disk 0` -- selects your hard disk.
- `clean` -- clears the partition table and erases all partitions. Make sure you have backup.
- `convert gpt` -- converts the disk to use GUID partition table if not already using. clean command should follow this.
- `create partition efi size=100` -- creates a 100MB efi partition. If your disk is using advanced format, change the value to 260.
- `format fs=fat32 quick label="efi"` -- Formats the efi partition with fat32 partition. When using format command, make sure the partition is selected by "list partition" command.
- `create partition msr size=128` -- creates 128MB msr partition.
- `create partition primary size=xxxx` -- create desired ntfs partition for windows C drive. The xxxx is partition size value in MB. Repeat this to create additional ntfs partitions for storage if needed.
- `format fs=ntfs quick label="somelabel"` -- formats the above created ntfs partitions.
- `create partition primary size=xxxx` -- create ext partitions for use with linux. Keep them unformatted.

Comment: "*I think msr partition should be after efi partition*" I agree, and so does the Microsoft tech website FAQ, but the auto (basic) install of WIn 10 puts it after MSR.One more question, if I create the partitions: EFI->MSR->NTFS (then unallocated space for Linux later) will Windows find and use these partitions? Or just create it's own again? (I hate the Win installer, it offers no options to manage such things).

Comment: Do you mean installing Windows >> Linux >> Reinstall Windows -- will it use old partitions?? If so, it should identify and use them. Windows will not always prompt you to erase your hard disk and create its own partitions.

Comment: Not about "reinstall" just this one run. If I create the 3 Windows partitions (EFI, MRS, data) will the Windows installer identify them from their label and use them to install? I suppose from here I can try it. You've answered my main questions. Cheers :) (spent 2 days playing around and reading and got to the stage where I just wanted someone to confirm)

Comment: Partition label is not what windows chooses to identify partitions. Partition id is used. With Gui partitioning during installation, you may not be able to create efi and msr partition types. I have edited my answer explaining the process in detail. Please go through it. Once you create the required partitions as mentioned above, Windows installer will identify them.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, that's cracking. I'll give that a go now :) Tho I read EFI should be 550MB or more otherwise Linux can get confused and not read fat32 under 550 (537 I think it was) given this is a tiny size I'll do this just for precautions sake. Cheers